# How to view 4K videos at lower resolution?

Tags: video, vlc, codecs, 4k-monitor

I'm trying to view some 4K resolution MP4 videos generated by a Galaxy Note 3 on my mid-2010 MacBook Pro 7, 1 running Ubuntu 13.10.

Using any of the standard major video players (VLC, Totem, etc.), I'm having difficulties seeing anything. Just as Evince presents PDFs in a limited resolution for the purposes of speed, is there a video player that can do something similar for the presentation of 4K video in a lower resolution so that I can view it? Alternatively, is there some fast way for me to convert the video files to files with specified lower resolutions?

Answer (score 2):

An easy way to view 4K videos is to use latest version of VLC, e.g. 2.2.1, which is now [4K-ready](https://www.videolan.org/vlc/releases/2.1.0.html). For some Ubuntu distros, you can install latest VLC from this PPA: 
[ppa:ed10vi86/video](https://launchpad.net/~ed10vi86/+archive/ubuntu/video).

Comment: I got version 2.2.4 running Antergos (Arch based) Linux. I still got a loppy lagging video with 4k. Mplayer works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Install ffmpeg.  Then, from the command line, `ffplay -vf scale=1600:900 my-4k-video.mp4` .

Or, `ffmpeg -i in.mov -c:v libx264 -vf scale=1600:900 -c:a copy out.mov` .

In either case, change the x- and y-resolutions 1600 and 900 as you wish.